# In drupal 7 views, can views data be cached for logged in authenticated users?

Tags: 7, views, caching

For drupal 7 views 3.x, can you cache the data for logged in authenticated users? And where would this setting be located? A screenshot would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You click on the Caching link (here shown in the lower portion of the right column) and click Time-based (or whatever other cache()ing you have implemented on your system).

[image: Views Caching]

Then you can tell Views how long you want the cache()ing to be on the next menu presented:

[image]